# Checking textual representation of a class in a test?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

Lets say I've created a class **MyClass** in Pharo Smalltalk...

If I in *Workspace* write:

> MyClass new.

and select *print-it* (Ctrl-P), I get:

> A MyClass

With a bit of tinkering with **MyClass**'s **printOn:** method, 
I could get a bit more, for example:

> A MyClass with value: 5

+++

So comes my question...  How can I make a *test* (instance of TestCase-class)
that checks that the textual-representation of **MyObject** - what I would get
if I did "MyObject new" and Print-It - is what it's supposed to be?

How do I get the textual representation so I can check it against a
string-constant with what it *should* be, when I do a *self* **assert: equal:** (or something similar) in my test?

For example that after using my cutomized **printOn:** method, it will
look something like

> A MyClass with value: 5

Sorry for such a newbie question, but there goes...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the textual representation of an object you can send the message `printString` to the object. For example `Object new printString` will return you the string `'an Object'`.

To create a test case you should create a subclass of `TestCase`:

```
TestCase subclass: #MyClassTestCase
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: ''
    package: 'MyTest-Package'
```

Then a test is a method that begins with `test`. For example the following test verifies the string representation of `Object new`:

```
testClassRepresentation
   self assert: Object new printString equals: 'an Object'
```